# Find logic in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to python..

In my test function I am passing some text data which considers `"invalid password"`.
In such case I return `Data_Check` as `"invalid password"` but now client as asked if `"invalid password"` is more than once in `data` variable then only return `"INVALID PASSWORD"` otherwise it should return `"VALID"` itself.

please tell me in below function what changes can be done.

```
def test(data):
    Data_Check = 'VALID'
    if (data.lower()).find('invalid password') >= 1:
        Data_Check = 'INVALID PASSWORD'
    return Data_Check
```

Comment: It helps if you can update your question with an example of what should happen.  It certainly looks like this will work.  But your explanation is not perfectly clear.  An example would be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.find(t)` will tell you the *position* of `t` in `s`, not how often `t` occurs in `s`.

Your want http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

```
if data.lower().count('invalid password') > 1:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Improvement on your solution:

```
if data.lower().count('invalid password') > 1:
    return 'INVALID PASSWORD'
return 'VALID'
```

One-liner solution:

```
return 'VALID' if data.lower().count('invalid password') <= 1 else 'INVALID PASSWORD'
```

And on a side note, you should separate your `if`'s "do something" block onto a new line.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. I'll fix it now.